# Checking the header checkbox when all the checkboxes in the table are checked

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, html-table

I want the header checkbox to get checked when all the checkboxes in the table are checked and if even a single checkbox is unchecked the header checkbox should be unchecked..

```
<html>
<table id="table" style="height:350px;margin-left:1em;width:700px;">
    <!--this is my table header-->
    <tr style="display:table-row">
        <th class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox"/></th>
        <th class="Name">NAME</th>
        <th class="Score">SCORE</th>
        <th class="Email">EMAIL</th>
        <th class="Empty"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <!--tabledata-->
        <td ><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td >Vijay Prakash</td>
        <td >34</td>
        <td >vijay@gmail.com</td>
        <td ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <!--tabledata-->
        <td ><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td >Sashi Pagadala</td>
        <td >21</td>
        <td >sashi@gmail.com</td>
        <td ></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" id="btnCalculate" value="Calculate"/>
<label>Average:</label>
<label id="lblAverage"></label>
<label>Max:</label>
<label id="lblMax"></label>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: Using jquery.........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this is what you are looking for.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wdakm/)

```
$('td input:checkbox').change(function(){
    $('th.checkbox :checkbox').prop('checked',$('td input:checkbox:checked').length == $('td input:checkbox').length);
});
```

Comment: @BharatBhushan No problem.. If you are satisfied with the answer please mark as answer. :)

Comment: I have a textbox outside the table....in which the user types some person name which is present in the table "NAME" column...Can we highlight all the table cells having the same value as textbox?